# How can i increase a counter via editText?

Tags: android

My program involves calculating multiple expenses, [image]

I made it so that you can increase or decrease the values using + or - buttons.

upon pressing on the buttons, it updates a counter which the program will then access to display total expenses.

i am now trying to update the counter via `EditText` but could not figure it out.
(basically, enter amount instead of relying on buttons)

This is my counterhandler code

```
    public class CounterHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int counter;
    private EditText editAmount;

    public int getCounter() { return counter; }

    public CounterHandler(ConstraintLayout layout) {
        editAmount = layout.findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
        layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus)
                .setOnClickListener(CounterHandler.this);
        layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus)
                .setOnClickListener(CounterHandler.this);
        counter = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonMinus) {
            counter = Math.max(0, --counter);
        }
        else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonPlus) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            counter = Integer.parseInt(editAmount.getText().toString());
        }
        editAmount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}
```

this is the **mainactivity** code where the program accessed the info and calculates the total expenses

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonCalculate) {

            totalSum = counterBills.getCounter() + counterDrink.getCounter() +
                    counterTransportation.getCounter() + counterRent.getCounter() +
                    counterMeal.getCounter() + counterCollege.getCounter() + counterOthers.getCounter();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summary.class);
            intent.putExtra("total", totalSum);
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total Expenses Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain what is unexpected behavior that is occurring currently?

Comment: You can do it by edittext.textChangeListener in which you can get text as soon as any change made in edittext and you can use for loop number of times with that number you wrote that how many times you want to increment or decrements  the counter.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the else case from your `onClickListener`, only update the text in EditText in case of plus and minus button clicks.
- For editing text in your EditText use `TextWatcher`.

  ```
      editAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          //Do nothing
      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          //Do nothing
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

          counter = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(s.toString())); 
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks Aman and abduaziz!
the code works!
i will need to spend some time understanding it though as i've never used text watche before

Comment: apparently the program sometimes crashes :S

error is found at the contents of afterTextChanged